# How to show live streaming video from RTSP server in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an  RTSP server end point from which i need to show live streaming video in asp.net webpage , how do i achieve it. Please provide me some sample code to achieve it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Comment: Did somebody help you with this problem?

Comment: I need it! :( 
News?